# Add Dropdown view inside a TextView

Tags: android

I have to create a layout where i need to display a paragraph on a TextView. Certain words in that paragraph need to be displayed inside a drop down view. Where do i get started with this ?

Kind Regards

Comment: You must be looking for a Spinner. See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you right - Like joao2fast4u said you can use Spinner or PopupMenu.
example with popupMenu:

```
PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(this, someButton);
popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.your_menu, popup.getMenu());
popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
        // switch your menu item and do something..
        return true;
    }
});
popup.show();
```